# nginx location proxy to subdomain

Tags: nginx, proxy, subdomain

in my setup i do have some subdomains. They are fully configured and working. 
For some reasons i need a proxy from my main domain to these sub domains.

eg. I have a sub named subdomain.domain.tdl and i want to pass all from domain.tld/p/subdomain to subdomain.domain.tdl

My config so far:

```
    location / {
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8002;
    }

# Proxy to subdomains
location ^/p/(.+)/(.*)$ {
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_pass http://$1.my-example-domain.tld/$2;
    }
```

but this is not working.
All requests to /p/subdomain/index.html are fetched by the node server running on localhost:8002

Can you give me some advice how to route /p/* to $1.my-example-domain/*?

Thanks a lot in advance. 
ps

*** UPDATE ***
This is my -V:

```
$ nginx -V
nginx version: nginx/1.2.1
TLS SNI support enabled
configure arguments: 
    --prefix=/etc/nginx 
    --conf-path=/etc/nginx/nginx.conf 
    --error-log-path=/var/log/nginx/error.log 
    --http-client-body-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/body 
    --http-fastcgi-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/fastcgi 
    --http-log-path=/var/log/nginx/access.log 
    --http-proxy-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/proxy 
    --http-scgi-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/scgi 
    --http-uwsgi-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/uwsgi 
    --lock-path=/var/lock/nginx.lock 
    --pid-path=/var/run/nginx.pid 
    --with-pcre-jit 
    --with-debug 
    --with-http_addition_module 
    --with-http_dav_module 
    --with-http_geoip_module 
    --with-http_gzip_static_module 
    --with-http_image_filter_module 
    --with-http_realip_module 
    --with-http_stub_status_module 
    --with-http_ssl_module 
    --with-http_sub_module 
    --with-http_xslt_module 
    --with-ipv6 
    --with-sha1=/usr/include/openssl 
    --with-md5=/usr/include/openssl 
    --with-mail 
    --with-mail_ssl_module 
    --add-module=/tmp/buildd/nginx-1.2.1/debian/modules/nginx-auth-pam 
    --add-module=/tmp/buildd/nginx-1.2.1/debian/modules/nginx-echo 
    --add-module=/tmp/buildd/nginx-1.2.1/debian/modules/nginx-upstream-fair 
    --add-module=/tmp/buildd/nginx-1.2.1/debian/modules/nginx-dav-ext-module
```

Comment: Looks ok, it should work. Try to enable debug http://nginx.org/en/docs/debugging_log.html , it should help you to figure out what's wrong

Comment: seams that something is wrong with my regex: 2015/02/12 12:57:22 [debug] 29530#0: *2 test location: "^/p/(.+)/(.*)$"
2015/02/12 12:57:22 [debug] 29530#0: *2 test location: "/"
2015/02/12 12:57:22 [debug] 29530#0: *2 using configuration "/"

Comment: maybe try to make it lazy ^/p/(.+?)/(.*)$

Comment: hm, even this: ^/p/(.*)$ does not work. /p/ works, but ^/p/ does not. Is there some regex global switch?

Comment: Ok location ~ ^/p/.+?/.*$ { works now. I forgot the ~sign.

Comment: but now i have a:  no resolver defined to resolve subdomain.domain.tld (domain edited.). if i call them directly all is file. I can ping the domain from the server, too.

Comment: Heh i missed this "~" sign too :) Use resolver directive http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#resolver

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to SuddenHead, this works:

```
location ~ ^/p/(.+?)/(.*)$ {
            resolver 8.8.8.8;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_pass http://$1.domain.tld/$2;
    }
```

i had to remove the host header and add a resolver.